# Using django filter and tags with angular expressions

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, django-templates

```
<img style="width: 40px; height: 39px" class="img-responsive" src="/static{{user.avatar|cut:"abc/static" }}" alt="{{ user.first_name }}">
```

The requirement of "cut" filter in the code above is because I get "abc/static/abc/uploads/profileimages/images_3.jpg" in user avatar(from django view) and I want to change to "/static/abc/uploads/profileimages/images_3.jpg" hence used this -
`/static{{user.avatar|cut:"abc/static" }}`

As cut filter is used in above code I need to use it in below code also but here I receive data from angular and cannot combine django "cut" with it:

```
<img ng-if="notif ==1 " class="user-img" src="/static{$ notif.about_user_image $}" alt="{$ notif.firstname $}">
```

Is it possible to use such django filters or tag in combination of angular?

Comment: Neither of those look particularly right to me... are you trying to do `{% static user.avatar %}`?

Comment: @Simer, can you be clearer on what you are trying to achieve. Your question is very open ended: Are you trying to use a combination of Angular AND Django or trying to replace Django functionality by Angular Functionality. If so, what is the specific functionality you're after? Ideally, can you try it first and show us what is not working in what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @raphv I have updated my question. It would be great if you provide some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] but here I receive data from angular and cannot combine django "cut" with it
>
> Is it possible to use such django filters or tag in combination of angular?

If you're thinking of passing a value from AngularJS to a Django filter that's not going to be possible, Django filter is ran server side before AngularJS even gets to execute on the browser.

If this is to be done when the data is loaded on the browser, then you'll want an [AngularJS filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter), below I assume default `{{` token, use your custom `{$` token if you want:

```
<img ng-src="{{ notif.about_user_image | processImageUrl }}" />
```

Please note the [**`ng-src`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) instead of `src`

Then you define a filter, e.g.

```
app.filter('processImageUrl', function() {
  return function(url) {
    return url.replace('abc/static/abc', '/static/mbp');
  };
})
```

Comment: Hi @bakkal thanks a ton for your response. Please let me implement the same to check the results.